# how to plot duplicated columns on python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this data where the year column is duplicated for every month from 2018 to 2022 i want to plot the ORDNUM on monthly basis with year as my legend here is the data

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2018, 2018, 2018, 2019], "Month": [3, 4, 5, 3], "ORDNUM": [4459, 2332, 1224, 4322]})
```

[image: the data frame view of it]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input data as text, not an image or link, as well as _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, and a description of what went wrong with your attempts, so that we can better understand how to provide specific help. Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code generates the following picture.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

data = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2018, 2018, 2018, 2019], "Month": [3, 4, 5, 3], "ORDNUM": [4459, 2332, 1224, 4322]})

seaborn.relplot(data=data, x="Month", y="ORDNUM", hue="Year")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @adika: Providing the `data = ...` line helps to directly get coding/solving your problem.  By posing an image, people have to do this dedious work manually ;)